# Finding a basis for set of equations that passes through specific points and prove it subspace.

Tags: vector-spaces, change-of-basis

> Consider the vector space of functions $y=ax^2 + bx+ c$ for real constants a,b,c. To each function we can associate the vector $(a,b,c)^T$ . Find a basis of the set of these functions that passes through the points (x,y) = (1,2) and (3,4) . Is this set a subspace? What is its dimension?

Here is what I am thinking:

1. Solving for the basis: 

    2 = (1)a + (1)b + c

    3 = (4)a + (2)b + c

This can be written in the form of the following matrix: 
$
\begin{bmatrix}
    1 &4 \\
    1 & 2 \\
    1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
$
which can be reduced to: 
$\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 \\
    0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
$

Thus, our basis is: 
 
$\begin{bmatrix}
    1  \\
    0  \\
    0 
\end{bmatrix}
$ , 
$\begin{bmatrix}
     0 \\
     1 \\
     0
\end{bmatrix}
$

and it follows that the dimension is 2. I am going in the correct direction?

2. How can prove this is a subspace?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

No. If you represent a quadratic polynomial by a column vector $\;\smash{\begin{bmatrix}a\\[-0.5ex]b\\[-1ex]c\end{bmatrix}}$,the system of linear equations you obtain is:
$$\begin{bmatrix}1&1&1 \\4&2&1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}a\\b\\c\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}2\\1\end{bmatrix}$$
This is a inhomogeneous linear system. Its solutions are an `affine` subspace, with direction the `vector` subspace of solutions of the associated homogeneous linear system. As the matrix has rank $2$, this subspace has codimension $2$, i.e. dimension $3-2=1$.

Comment: thanks! but don't we need any proof that it is a subspace? and what about the basis?

Comment: As  I explain in my sketch, it is *not* a vector subspace. However the *differences* of any two solutions *are* a vector subspace (of dimension $1$), because they're the set of solutions  of a system $AX=0$. A basis of this subspace is obtained as usual by full row-reduction.